# Package okhttp3.logging does not exist

Tags: java, okhttp

I try to use `okhttp3.logging` to log my retrofit http request.

I add the dependency in the `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
  <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
  <version>3.12.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Unfortunately I have a problem during the import:

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
```

Here is the error when compiling:

```
ERROR] /Users/martin/dev/adm/usersync/usersync-connectors/usersync-connector-discourse/src/main/java/org/xwiki/contrib/usersync/discourse/internal/DiscourseUserSyncConnector.java:[84,48] package HttpLoggingInterceptor does not exist
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you need

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 8):

the versions of the okhttp3 and okhttp3:logging-interceptor dependencies needed to exactly match. So for example:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to consult the Maven Repository site

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/logging-interceptor/3.12.1

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/logging-interceptor -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: in gradle file change the next configuration

```
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```